# how to retrive max product_id count from order_detail table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select max(count(od_product_id)) as no from order_detail group by od_product_id
```

above the query doen't work.

Comment: *above the query doen't work.* - Really isn't helpful. What error does it show?

Comment: i want to retrive product_id and counted product_id both

Comment: Clearly you didn't read my comment, you just copied and pasted your earlier comment.

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1111 - Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` for this

```
SELECT od_product_id, COUNT(od_product_id) AS c
FROM order_detail 
GROUP by od_product_id
HAVING count(od_product_id) >= ALL
(
    SELECT count(od_product_id)
    FROM order_detail 
    GROUP by od_product_id
)
```

Comment: i want to retrive product_id and counted product_id both

Comment: @MyoMaMa Are you kidding me? The `od_product_id` and its count is in the result! You have no `product_id` in your query as well.

Comment: ohn.. sorry i'm wrong another max query. now i got it thz u xo much.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to group by the column you are aggregating

Try this:

```
select max(counted) 
from
(
select od_product_id, count(*) as counted
from order_detail
group by od_product_id
) x1
```

Comment: i want to retrive product_id and counted product_id both

Comment: ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1 seems simpler

Comment: @Strawberry Probably would be, I went ANSI though

Comment: Sure you did ;-)